# RedisSystemException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I meet this exception when using jedis with spring-data-redis in multi threading environment:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Unknown redis exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.getFallback(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:48)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:38)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:241)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.rPush(JedisConnection.java:1705)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations$14.doInRedis(DefaultListOperations.java:187)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations$14.doInRedis(DefaultListOperations.java:184)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:207)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations.rightPush(DefaultListOperations.java:184)
        at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:265)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.rpush(BinaryJedis.java:1053)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.rPush(JedisConnection.java:1703)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

jedis version: **2.9.0**

spring-data-redis version: **1.8.12.RELEASE**

redis server version: **3.0.6**

My Client Java Code:

```
// Init JedisConnectionFactory
JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxActive);
jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(maxWait);
jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);

jedisConnectionFactory.setPoolConfig(jedisPoolConfig);
jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
jedisConnectionFactory.setTimeout(timeout);
jedisConnectionFactory.setPassword(password);
jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

// Create RedisTemplate
redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
StringRedisSerializer serializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(serializer);
redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(serializer);
redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(serializer);
redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(serializer);
redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my problem by remove this line, after I read the source code of `spring-data`:

```
redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should share the pool and get a different Jedis from it in every thread.

See more on [GitHub](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started#using-jedis-in-a-multithreaded-environment)

This is a recurring pattern on [Samebug](https://samebug.io/error-patterns/113424). Try to [search with your stack trace](https://samebug.io/search).

Comment: I think this line `jedisConnectionFactory.setPoolConfig(jedisPoolConfig);` already build a jedis share pool. Or could you share the correct spring-data-redis and jedic config code ? Thanks